# Sha512 hashing in the Hashlib library producing different results each time the code is run

Tags: python, hashlib

I am trying to create a system that can hash a password, then I can store the hash and compare the hash to the inputted password. The issue is that whenever I run this code the hashes it produces are different with the same input. I have found out that the code produces the same output every execution on the same run, but is not consistent between runs.

Code:

```
import hashlib

def Sha512Hash(Password):
    HashedPassword=hashlib.sha512(Password.encode('utf-8'))
    print(HashedPassword)

Sha512Hash('Hi')
Sha512Hash('Hi')
```

Comment: What exactly is your current output…?

Comment: You aren't printing out the hash, you're printing out the object that calculates the hash - which includes an address that is essentially meaningless (and does not depend in any way on the string being hashed).  Call `.hexdigest()` or `.digest()` on the 'sha512' object to actually calculate the hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code :

```py
import hashlib

def Sha512Hash(Password):
    HashedPassword=hashlib.sha512(Password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    print(HashedPassword)

Sha512Hash('Hi')
Sha512Hash('Hi')
```

And your output will be like this which do not have any problem

```
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to hashing so I didn't know I had to digest the hashing algorithm before I could use it

Comment: you're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Hi it's quite likely that you missinterpreted output.

I saved your script and invoked it with python2 and python3. Python3 reused the object (or it address), but python2 created new object.

```
python2 x.py 
<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f47a870bc30>
<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f47a870bc00>

python3 x.py
<sha512 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7fb842d51bb0>
<sha512 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7fb842d51bb0>
```

After the `@` there is memory address. But if you change script so it print hexdigest (representation in hexadecimal). You will be able to see that it's working as expected.

```
def Sha512Hash(Password):
    HashedPassword = hashlib.sha512(Password.encode('utf-8'))
    print(HashedPassword)
    print(HashedPassword.hexdigest())
```

Invocation of changed script:

```
python2 x.py
<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f2bbe8dbc30>
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d
<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f2bbe8dbc00>
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d

python3 x.py
<sha512 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7f41df832bb0>
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d
<sha512 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7f41df832bb0>
45ca55ccaa72b98b86c697fdf73fd364d4815a586f76cd326f1785bb816ff7f1f88b46fb8448b19356ee788eb7d300b9392709a289428070b5810d9b5c2d440d
```